# repeating header in BI publisher template

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher, xml-publisher, oracle-xml-publisher

I am trying to design a template in BI publisher for the xml file generated by oracle BI PUBLISHER.

I want my header part to repeat on all the pages
like if the data is printed across pages the header portion related to the data should be printed on all the pages.

I tried to include the repeating group in header and its end tag in body, but its not working for me.

header section is related to body and each group can have different headers
Can any one help me on this?

Comment: What kind of template are you working on ? Is it RTF template ? And is the header just some static text  or data ?

Comment: Yes i am working on rtf template and the header includes the data as well. I know in header we have to use tags instead of fields. But the problem is that i want to include the header in the group which will have its end tag in body. Header will be different for each record.

Comment: The header in these templates are for static text/images and page numbers, the page breaking is controlled by BIP when the data overflows one page. So if you need your header to change, the logic is more complex. Why don't you post a sample of your xml, and the desired output, so we can figure out how to achieve it ?

Comment: okay.. my requirement is something like this -  lets take an example of emp-dept. i have a list of a emp and dept. 1 dept can have hundred of emp. that means one department can have more than one page.. so i want to have the dept in the header section so that the dept will be printed on all the pages that consist data for that particular dept.

Comment: Even i want to have dynamic image in the header section. for each dept, the department logo will be picked from a specific folder in the drive depending upon the name of the dept. (means image name will be same as dept name). i am able to do that in body section. but not in header. so thats why i want to start my group from the header to body.. i even tried <?start:body?> and <?end:body?> tags. but i am not getting the solution. can you please help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a two level hierarchy in the xml, you want the value for level1 to be repeated across pages, if data in level2 overflows. This can be achieved with the `<?for-each@section:LEVEL?>` command

```
<?for-each@section:LEVEL1?>
<?for-each:LEVEL2?>
<?name?>
<?end for-each?>
<?end for-each?>
```

Now you need to give `<?LEVEL1?>` in your header. It will be printed across pages when its Level2 records overflow.

Comment: Yes.. this is working. thanks a lot bro.. sorry for the late reply

Comment: Nice to know ! Please mark the answer if it worked for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Bi Publisher Layout and then choose Page Layout near the Insert Tab.
Click page header,add there put whatever you want .
I attach you screenshot.

[image]